# getIntent().getExtras.getInt("ID"); retrieving null value

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to pass the Id of the image inorder to delete the entry from the listview using a notification. But the value of the delGoalId is showing "null". Help me please.

Error: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

AlarmReceiver.java

```
 Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            deleteIntent.setAction("Delete");
            //onReceive(position, mContext, deleteIntent);
            deleteIntent.putExtra("ID", MyImageID.get(0));
            deleteIntent.putExtra("update", true);
            deleteIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

MainActivity.java

```
OnCreate()

int delGoalId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("ID");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"delGoalId value :"+delGoalId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 if (delGoalId >= 0) {
                onReceive(delGoalId);
            }
```

OnReceive()

```
 public void onReceive(final int position) {
    final SwipeMenuListView swipelist = (SwipeMenuListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onReceive", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final MyImage image = (MyImage) swipelist.getItemAtPosition((int) position);
    String action = getIntent().getAction();

    if ("Delete".equals(action)) {// to execute delete option
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        //Yes button clicked
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), image + " " + " is deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("Delete Image: ", "Deleting.....");
                        adapter.remove(adapter.getItem((int) position));
                        swipelist.invalidateViews();
                        File fdelete = new File(image.getTitle());
                        if (fdelete.exists())

                        {
                            if (fdelete.delete()) {
                                daOdb.deleteImage(image);
                                daOdb.getImages();
                                // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
                                myGoalNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                // Builds the notification and issues it.
                                myGoalNotifyMgr.cancel(position);
                                System.out.println("File Deleted :" + image.getPath());
                            } else {
                                daOdb.deleteImage(image);
                                daOdb.getImages();
                                System.out.println("File Not Deleted :" + image.getPath());
                            }
                        }
                        swipelist.invalidateViews();
                        dialog.cancel();
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        //No button clicked
                        dialog.cancel();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Do You Wish To Delete?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: what type of data does MyImageID holds?

Comment: @Jack'sretardedcode ArrayList<Integer> MyImageID = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: MyImageID  having value at 0 position right? @SoniaWadji please check that also

Comment: @KDeogharkar Yes. It is having a value at position 0.

Comment: `Log.d` the value of `MyImageID.get(0)` in your receiver

Comment: @pskink The value is showing in the log as 2 which is the id of the entry in the listview for which notification has been set.

Comment: and what about `Log.d(TAG, "intent: " + getIntent());` in MainActivity?

Comment: @pskink Intent:﹕ Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=camera.fizz5.com.cameramodule/.MainActivity }

Comment: so it has no "extras" who starts that activity? seems it is started by a home launcher

Comment: @pskink So what do i have to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107405/discussion-between-soniawadji-and-pskink).